# Sending notifications via Messenger Bot to Facebook OAuth registered users

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-messenger

Let's say you have a site that accepts Facebook OAuth registrations/login. Today, the typical pattern is to capture the user's email and send them notifications via that channel. Fine.

Messenger bots have now opened up an opportunity to engage with users directly via Messenger rather than relying on email. In markets where Messenger is heavily used and email hardly ever, notifications via Messenger are a big deal.

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference) my understanding is that Facebook user id's are application scoped. I wouldn't be able to send a user registered via Facebook's OAuth a message on Messenger.

Has anyone done this? Is it possible or at least being considered in a future spec?

Comment: The user has to initiate the conversation with your bot in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use checkbox plugin for messenger in web app flow, this is meant for the same purpose!

Comment: Looks like this was added just earlier this month (the 8th?). Thanks for catching this!

Comment: Yups, anyways do you have any idea of using this plugin inside Facebook Tab/canvas  App?

Comment: We will likely use it to send notifications for users signed up/logged in via their Facebook account.